# java how to use printf

Tags: java, printf

I am trying to use printf to display something like this:

```
Temperature: # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

but when I run my program, I get this:

```
Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:Temperature:
  69.0      67.0      66.0      64.0      66.0      69.0      67.0      67.0      70.0      69.0      69.0      70.0
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
System.out.printf("Temperature:", "%10.1f", temperature);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `System.out.printf("Temperature: %10.1f", temperature);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that you are using a loop or not.

If you are using for loop then write  `System.out.print("Temperature:");` outside the loop.
then inside the loop you can write `System.out.print(temperature+"\t");`

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
System.out.printf("Temperature %10.1f\n", temperature)
```

Comment: this does not give the expected `Temperature: # # # # # # # # # # # #` format

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this depending on what you want.

If you are using a Collection to store the temperatures, you can iterate through them and print each temp with a space or tab between them.

```
System.out.print("Temperature: ");
for(int temp: temps)
{
    System.out.print(temp + " ");
}
```

If you don't care too much about the format of the output you could do the following:

```
System.out.printf("Temperature: %s", Arrays.toString(temperature.toArray()));
```

That will give you this:

```
Temperature: [10.0, 15.0, 20.0]
```

The last answer will of course only work in situations where your objects have a toString() implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like:

```
String temp = "";

for (strintg s : Temperature){
     temp+= s + " "; }

System.out.printf("Temperature: " + temp);
```

Pass all the info from the temperature array into a string ahead of time and then print it out as one string.